# How to make curve cylinder?

Tags: bezier-curves

How to make curve cylinder? Now I have a static ones, but I would like to make them curve. Is it possible to change them somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Here are 3 solutions: ***Curve*** modifier, **bezier** curve, and ***Bridge Edge Loop***:

[image]

You can also create 2 or more circles, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*:

[image]

Then tweak the settings (particularly *Number of Cuts* and *Smoothness*) in the *Operator* box:

[image]